# Using inline code to generate file path in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to include an image stored in a package in my Rmarkdown document.
I can do this using:

```
![](C:/Documents/R/mypackage/inst/images/myimage.jpg)
```

However, this won't work on my colleagues machines if the package has a different file path. Therefore I wan't to use the below:

```
![](`r system.file("images", "myimage.jpg", package = "mypackage")`)
```

But this fails and gives the following message when I try to knit using knitr:

```
pandoc.exe: Could not find image `', skipping...
```

I also tried the below which fails in the same way:

```
---
output: word_document
params:
 d: !r system.file("images", "myimage.jpg", package = 
"mypackage")
---

![](`r params$d`)
```

Comment: How are you sharing the markdown file(s) with yor colleagues? I would save the image in your working directory

Comment: How are you sharing the packages with your colleagues? what does it give you `getwd()`? and `.libPaths()`?

Comment: the package is shared via devtools::install_github(). my colleagues could save the image to their working directory but I don't wan't to have to distribute images along with the rmarkdown file, since they will already have the image stored in their package library. However I won't know that file path which is unique to their machine - hence needing to use system.file()

Comment: Maybe `find.package` will help? E.g. `find.package('data.table')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this working now - the problem was that I was trying to knit after having used devtools::load_all() in my package development directory. The below works fine if I install my package using devtools::install_github() and then knit.

```
![](`r system.file("images", "myimage.jpg", package = "mypackage")`)
```